# alpine Linux: my application is not found

Tags: docker, rust, alpine-linux

I use multi stage docker to build my rust app.

I use alpine as builder. Building is successfull for both x86_64 and aarch64.

The final docker image is also based on alpine.

I can start the x86_64 image, I can see my app log.
On aarch64 device (Rpi3) I start my image but get `exec : myapp not found`

After some googling, it's an issue with musl ldd

I do `lld myapp`

Get

```
/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x7fa2006000)
        libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x7fa1ef1000)
        libpq.so.5 => /usr/lib/libpq.so.5 (0x7fa1e90000)
        libmariadb.so.3 => /usr/lib/libmariadb.so.3 (0x7fa1e2c000)
        libc.musl-aarch64.so.1 => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x7fa2006000)
        libssl.so.3 => /lib/libssl.so.3 (0x7fa1d88000)
        libcrypto.so.3 => /lib/libcrypto.so.3 (0x7fa1a02000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x7fa19d1000)
```

So I get no issue.

I don't inderstand what is wrong

Edit : my dockerfile
I run in from x86_64 host (GHA)

```
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM node as build-frontend 
WORKDIR /opt/lucle
COPY . . 
RUN cd web && yarn install --network-timeout 500000
RUN cd web && yarn build

FROM rust:alpine3.17 as alpine-builder-amd64
RUN apk add --update mysql mysql-client mariadb-dev postgresql postgresql-client postgresql-dev sqlite sqlite-dev musl-dev protobuf
WORKDIR /opt/lucle
COPY . . 
RUN cargo build --release --verbose

FROM --platform=linux/arm64 rust:alpine3.17 as alpine-builder-arm64
RUN apk add --update git mysql mysql-client mariadb-dev postgresql postgresql-client postgresql-dev sqlite sqlite-dev musl-dev protobuf
WORKDIR /opt/lucle
COPY . . 
RUN CARGO_NET_GIT_FETCH_WITH_CLI=true cargo build --release --verbose

FROM alpine-builder-$TARGETARCH as build

FROM alpine:3.17 as alpine
WORKDIR /opt/lucle
COPY --from=build /opt/lucle/target/release/lucle .
COPY --from=build-frontend /opt/lucle/web/dist ./web/dist
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["./lucle"]
```

Edit2: trying with full path, still get issue

Edit3: Trying to build from a native arm64 device, still get issue

Comment: It might be a good idea to share the dockerfile used to build the image you're having trouble with.

Comment: I update my post with dockerfile